# MS Chart control with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

Ive got a MS Chart control and it works just fine except that I can't figure out how to "format" the Y-Axis. I am adding a lot of double numbers into a Serie but when the double numb are actually whole numbers (20.000000.....) the Y-Axis on my chart shows 20.

example: this serie :
12.32
11.00
10.13
would actually show up like this:
12.32
11
10.13

I have tried formatting the data as I insert it into the serie like this:

```
serie.Points.AddXY(date.ToString(),double[i].ToString("##.##"));
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I've tried to search for a place to format it in Chart.Series[0].* and Chart.ChartAreas[0].* but I didn't find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Use "0.00" as format string, "##.##" will strip zeros at the end

```
serie.Points.AddXY(date.ToString(),double[i].ToString("0.00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might come too late, but here's my advice.

You can find out more about numeric format for strings, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

I think you need [fixed point ("F") format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString) used like this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "F2";
```

Also you should add numbers to your data points' Y values, not strings.
Hope that helps.